# WebWorker failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReaderSync'

Tags: angularjs, cordova, filesystems, cordova-plugins, web-worker

I have an application that take photo/video and send it to the server where this photo/video saving.

To take photo I am using cordova-plugins:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureImage(
                    function (fileURL) {
                        defer.resolve(fileURL);
                    },
                    function (errorData) {
                        defer.reject(errorData);
                    });
```

My task is to create WebWorker that will process file on background (not in main thread):

- will take base64 from File
- will send base64 to the server (server saving this data into DB)

To code it I am using:

- VisualStudio Enterprise 2015 with update 1
- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova update 3 (Cordova v5.3.3)
- AngularJS v1.4.8

Everything work great when I am not using WebWorker:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                    fileURL,
                    function (fileEntry) {
                        return fileEntry.file(function(data) {
                           var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                                InsertMedia(...); // data inserted on my server
                            };
                            //convert file to base64 formats
                            reader.readAsDataURL(data);
                        });
                    },
                    function (errorData) {
                        defer.reject(errorData);
                    });
```

Then I created WebWorker called 'doWork.js':

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    var data = e.data;  
    try
    {
        self.postMessage(e.data instanceof File); // will return 'false'
        var reader = new FileReaderSync();
        reader.readAsDataURL(data);
    }
    catch (err) {
        self.postMessage(err.message);
    }
}, false);
```

And used this worker from the main thread:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                    fileURL,
                    function (fileEntry) {
                        return fileEntry.file(function (data) {
                            alert(data instanceof File); // will return 'true'
                            var worker = new Worker('doWork.js');
                            worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                                alert(e.data);
                            }, false);
                            worker.postMessage(data);
                        });
                    },
                    function (errorData) {
                        defer.reject(errorData);
                    });
```

And after using WebWorker I always getting this issue:
**WebWorker failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReaderSync': A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed**

***How could I work with files inside WebWorker?***

Comment: Strange, I had no problem parsing files in web worker. I don't have time to replicate your problem - could you please make test-case yourself? Create a simple example, for example on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: To make a test need to use "navigator.device.capture.captureImage" that return as a result fileUrl (something like: "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/Pictures/1449665763305.jpg"). Then, using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and `FileEntry` I am getting `File` in main thread and it could be read by `FileReader` (of course in main thread). But when I am passing this `File` to `WebWorker` there I debugged that `data instanceof File` return `false` and that's why I can't  use `reader.readAsDataURL(data)` in WebWorker for picture took by cordova-capture-plugin

Comment: One more test have done: I tried to put `<input type='file` on my screen and used 'document.getElementById('files').files[0]' to pass in `WebWorker`- it's working great and I was able to extract `reader.readAsDataURL(data)`. And now it's confusing me what is wrong with `File` that I am getting using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and `FileEntry`; why `WebWorker` can't read  this `File`?

Comment: What is `e.data` within `message` handler?